# jQuery UI.hide('slide') strange behaviour with margins

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI's `.hide('slide')` animation on a number of elements. The problem is that when I specify a `margin` on these elements, the animation seems to jump down, and once complete, returns to its original position. If I remove the `margin` from these elements, the problem ceases to exist.

#### [I've set up a simplified example fiddle showing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/s5U38/14/)

### CSS

```
div.score {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
```

### jQuery

```
$('div.score').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 250, function() {
        $this.show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 250)
             .text(parseInt($this.text(), 10) + 1);
    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<div class="score">0</div>
<div class="score">0</div>
```

Could anyone explain what the reason for this is, is it a bug?

Comment: This is a known bug in the current effects plugin. We're in the middle of a rewrite of the effects plugins rewrite that will address this issue. This buggy described is also described in http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8505

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`div.ui-effects-wrapper` wraps you element `div.score` before animation (jQuery UI). Script calculates its height with `outerHeight(true)` method including margins http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight.

So `div.ui-effects-wrapper` height is `div.score` height + `div.score` margin -> `52px`

But your element still has margin rule, so actual wrapper height is `52px + 20px = 72px`.

I think this is a bug.

You can use this version (with simple wrapper)
http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/s5U38/31/

Comment: It is a bug. We're in the middle of a rewrite of the effects plugins rewrite that will address this issue. This buggy described is also described in http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8505

Answer (score 2):

I solve this with another div as container, which has needed margin and counter itself has no margin:

**HTML**

```
<div class="slideContainer">
    <div class="score">0</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.slideContainer {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nPjEG/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin: auto 0 10px;` or `magin: auto 10px 10px;` instead of `margin: 10px;`